# Robot framework call soap method with Array parameter

Tags: robotframework

I have a Java Soap service with method

```
public void helloStudentsName(String[] names)
```

And user robot framework (SudsLibrary) to call this, because i didn't fine Array in Robot so i use List in code

```
 ${names}    Create List    name1    name2    name3
    Call Soap Method    helloStudentsName    ${names}
```

I got error

```
TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'arg0'
```

And replace $ by @ in list declare

```
@{names}    Create List    name1    name2    name3
    Call Soap Method    helloStudentsName    @{names}
```

No error but in Java method receive an empty array.

Can you show me how to call this method?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a special WSDL array object, rather than using a plain robot list. SudsLibrary has a keyword for this, and uses it in an example.

Assuming your WSDL defines a type of ArrayOfString, you might do something like this:

```
| | ${string array}= | Create Wsdl Object | ArrayOfString
| | Append To List | ${string array} | name1
| | Append To List | ${string array} | name2
| | Append To List | ${string array} | name3
| | ${result}= | Call Soap Method | helloStudentsName | ${string array}
```

This will only work if your WSDL defines a type of `ArrayOfString`. Your actual WSDL might call it by some other name.